# How to get search engine name using google analytic api

Tags: php, google-analytics

Is there any way to get the top search engine name using Google analytic  api for a particular domain in php

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('source'),array('visits','pageviews','organicSearches'),array('-visits'),'',$startDate, $endDate, $startIndex, $maxResults);
```

this code returns the source which this domain visited but can i get the search engine from which the domain has a hit.

Comment: folks will more inclined to help if you post examples of things you have already tried

Comment: Segment by ga:medium="organic"

Comment: @Eduardo it shows only the organic/refreall is there any way get search engine name (google,yahoo) instead od of above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source is the correct dimension to request to get which search engine it is (i.e. Google, Bing, Yahoo). However I think @Eduardo is correct, I don't see a Medium filter (ga:medium="organic"). Without the Medium filter the source is going to have every source and make it hard to find the ones that are search engines.